# Kinks in the eigenvalue spectrum of short range lattices

Tags: graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-graph-theory

Take a periodic one-dimensional lattice of size $N$ with $2k$ nearest neighborers. That is, vertex $i$ is connected to $i+1,i+2,...,i+k$ and $i-1,i-2,...i-k$ (with the understanding that the indices are modulo $N$). Call the associated adjacency matrix $A_k$, and consider the limit of large $N$.

If I'm not mistaken, the eigenvalue spectrum for $A_1$ can be well approximated by a cosine wave with amplitude $2$ and period $2N$.

**Main Question**

Why does the spectra for $A_2$ have a 'kink'?

**Side Questions**

Why does the kink in $A_2$ appear at a magnitude of zero?

Why do the kinks in $A_3$ appear touch exactly when the curve hits the spectra for $A_2$ (it looks that after a certain point, one graph is supported by the other).

In general, the spectra for $A_k$ seem to have $k-1$ kinks, can this be shown?

[I've included an example of the spectra for $N=2^{11}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fobKG.png)

Comment: I count $2k$ nearest neighbors.

Comment: @joriki - you're correct, there are $2k$ nearest neighbors (mistyped)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvectors of such a [circulant matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix) are $(v_j)_m=\exp(2\pi \mathrm i jm/N)$. The corresponding eigenvalue spectra are the linear combinations of exponentials corresponding to a row of the matrix. For your $A_k$, these combinations are

$$\lambda_{kl}=\sum_{j=1}^k \cos(2\pi\mathrm i jl)\;,$$

Here are plots of the spectra [for $A_2$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20cos%28x%29%20%2b%20cos%282x%29) and [for $A_3$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20cos%28x%29%20%2b%20cos%282x%29%20%2b%20cos%20%283x%29). If you reorder them in descending order, as it seems that you have, then once your sort hits a maximum, you suddenly have three branches instead of just one, and also the eigenvalues are more dense around the maxima; that accounts for the kinks. The second, "inverse" kink for $A_3$ is caused by the minimum in the spectrum.